# Searching A delimited file for lines containing a set of possible strings, without displaying lines containing string-somethingelse

Tags: bash, grep, comm

```
grep -f strings.txt matrixToBeSearched.txt
```

if my string is `abc` and the `delimitedFile.txt` has the line `abc-def`, it will count that as a match, even if I use `-w` option. I need to only see lines containing abc.

My matrix is huge and my list of strings are huge, so I really need to use `-f` option rather than `-e`.

search for string abc in the following delimited file

```
|abc    |123|456  
|abc-def|789|123 
|abc    |456|789
```

**Output**

```
|abc    |123|456  
|abc    |456|789
```

Comment: You do not have a *"matrix"* in bash. There is no such thing. You have a *delimited file* you are attempting to parse with `grep` (and put **4-spaces** before each row in your question before the contents of your file to have them formatted in fixed-font)

Comment: The simple way to fix your problem given what you show is `grep 'abc[^-]' file.txt` where you search for `abc` NOT followed by a `'-'`.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
|abc    |123|456  
|abc-def|789|123 
|abc    |456|789 
|def    |012|345
```

You could use `awk` for this to get *exact* matches for a given string:

```
$ awk -F'[| ]' -v tgt='abc' '$2==tgt {print $0}' file
|abc    |123|456  
|abc    |456|789
```

And since `{print $0}` is the default action (as pointed out by Ed Morton) you can simplify to:

```
$ awk -F'[| ]' -v tgt='abc' '$2==tgt' file
```

Then if you wanted to have a file of fixed string to use:

```
$ cat tgts
abc
def
```

You can now use this `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[| ]'  'FNR==NR{tgt[$1]; next} # read the fixed strings 
                 $2 in tgt' tgts file
|abc    |123|456  
|abc    |456|789 
|def    |012|345
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is modified to be more clearly.

What you need can be

```
$ grep -Pf strings.txt matrixToBeSearched.txt
```

where

```
$ cat strings.txt
\|abc\s*\|
```

For example,

```
$ cat matrixToBeSearched.txt
|abc    |123|456  
|abc-def|789|123 
|abc    |456|789 
$ grep -Pf strings.txt matrixToBeSearched.txt
|abc    |123|456  
|abc    |456|789
```

Here I use `-P` parameter for a Perl regular expression.

You may modify the content of `strings.txt` for a better and stronger grep method.

Comment: However, I think this is just a temporary workaround, I also expect a better (and maybe tricky) answer.

Comment: Maybe use `awk`?

Comment: Thanks so much! Quick question, how could I amend `\|abc\s*\|` to prevent characters before. To continue this example, I want to find abc, not def-abc or abc-def. Your example works for the latter, is their an easy adjustment to make it work in both cases?

Comment: Oh? I added a line `|def-abc|123|456` to `matrixToBeSearched.txt` and didn't modify `strings.txt`, the result keep the same? What happened to you?

Answer (score 0):

`-w` considers `-` to be a word separator because it would not be part of a variable name in bash, i.e., `var=1; echo $var-iable` would yield "1-iable"

You can edit edit your list of strings to match your core word "abc" with only `|` or   on the side with `[| ]abc[| ]`. Or you can do as @David suggested and use `abc[^-]` to avoid grabbing dashes.

There isn't a grep flag that will let your "abc" in strings.txt match `|abc |` but not `|abc-def |`. You'll have to edit your list of strings to get this functionality.